# align buttons - bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a look at the below example.

[Sample](http://www.bootply.com/EzLtLNjS69)

I am trying to align the Button 1 on the extreme left and Button 2 and Button 3 on the extreme right. Is there a better way to do this rather than offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add this to the div containing the right buttons:

```
text-align:right;
```

You don't need the offset given your current setup because you are using pull-right.

If you want it to behave similarly on small screens, change the col-md to col-xs otherwise the width will default to 100% being a block level element.

Sample with xs: http://www.bootply.com/s8T3y5qJ7c

Comment: can u update the bootply sample I have given in my question. Also the mobile view of the buttons is not aligned.

Comment: Updated my answer. I assume you mean xs screens. In that case you want to use col-xs intead of md.

Comment: works fine...is there a way i can keep the width of the button constant?

Comment: From what I have seen, the button widths typically stay pretty constant with changing screen sizes. If you want the same size with differing button text lengths, you can create a class similar to what I did but use the width property and apply the class to the button(s).

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6 pull-right">
     <button type="reset" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-default">
        Button 2</button>
     <button type="reset" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-default">
        Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Here is your updated script:

[here](http://www.bootply.com/zJHdAuLoG8)